# ST3: Annoying file changed reload popups

Tags: macos, version-control, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I use sublime text for my editors. I love it for everything else but 1 thing which is so annoying according to me. Whenever I change my branch, it brings up a pop up saying that file has changed and if I want to reload the file. I have attached an image for it as well.

[image: Popup Image]

I have researched a lot on this and found few preferences: `ignoreChanged` and `autoReloadChanged` which are set to true. It doesn't make any difference. I need some help to fix this annoying issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you rather it do? Automatically reload or simply ignore the change completely? You say in your question that both `ignoreChanged` and `autoReloadChanged` are both true, but they both can't be true, can they?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find the key words (`ignoreChanged` and `autoReloadChanged`) you mention in the current documentation of Sublime Text 3, so probably they are from version 2 or even older.

The relevant part from the default settings is IMHO:

```
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": false,
```

As you can see this is disabled by default, but perhaps somewhere in you config (packages(?)) it gets activated. So try to set `always_prompt_for_file_reload` to `false`. Then Sublime Text silently reload a file if it detects any changes to it.

And please note the comment about unsaved files. I use the following setting, as I think it's quite handy, especially if you use *focus follow mouse* in your OS, but this might depend on you personal preferences:

```
// Set to true to automatically save files when switching to a different file
// or application
"save_on_focus_lost": false,
```

Comment: It didn't work for me? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to start from the default config, i.e. without personal config and without any plugins?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Windows 7 64b.